# Convert object by reflection

Tags: c#, object, system.reflection

I want to convert an object A to object B. The classes A and B have the same properties, just the names are changed.

I use this method:

```
 /// <summary>

    internal static T objectMapper<T>(object objectSource, T objectTarget)
    {
        dynamic o = objectSource;

        Type typeA = objectSource.GetType();
        Type typeB = objectTarget.GetType();
        IList<PropertyInfo> propsA = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeA.GetProperties());
        IList<PropertyInfo> propsB = new List<PropertyInfo>(typeB.GetProperties());


        dynamic s;

        ArrayList listArray = new ArrayList();

        foreach (var prop in propsA)
        {
            s = objectSource.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(objectSource, null);
            listArray.Add(s);
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var prop in propsB)
        {
            prop.SetValue(objectTarget, listArray[i], null);
            i++;
        }
        return objectTarget;


    }
```

How can I edit properties of `objectB` in the `foreach` loop? I want to use a generic method for different objects.

Comment: By converting do you mean Casting ( changing types) or copy values from the properties of the first class to the second?

Comment: change the type and copy the values. I use object because I do not know the object A and B (rather I will use this method for different classes).
i tried objectB=objectA but objectb change the type et become ojbect from class A

Comment: How are you going to determine that one specific property of object A will recieve another specific property of object B ?

Comment: class A {
            public int prop1 { get; set; }
            public int prop2 { get; set; }
        }
        class B
        {
            public int prop1 { get; set; }
            public int prop2 { get; set; }
        }
Class A and Class B have the same properties.
so objectA.prop1=objectB.prop1
objectA.prop2=objectB.prop2

Comment: Ok, so they will have the same names?

Comment: yes the properties will have the same names.

Comment: Then you should define an interface that contains all the properties and also an copy-from method...

Comment: yes but my classes are located in differents assemblies :(

Comment: If you have the interface in it's own assembly then you can reference it from the other assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

This solution provides both your reflection-way and an alternative way by defining and implementing a copy method `CopyFrom`. To reduce code you could make the interface a base-class so you don't need to implement `CopyFrom` in the sub-classes....

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    int Prop1 { get; set; }
    string Prop2 { get; set; }
    void CopyFrom(MyInterface obj);
}

public class A: MyInterface
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public void CopyFrom(MyInterface obj)
    {
        this.Prop1 = obj.Prop1;
        this.Prop2 = obj.Prop2;
    }
}
public class B: MyInterface
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public void CopyFrom(MyInterface obj)
    {
        this.Prop1 = obj.Prop1;
        this.Prop2 = obj.Prop2;
    }
}

public static class CopyUtils
{
    public static void Copy(MyInterface src, MyInterface dst)
    {
        var props = typeof(MyInterface).GetProperties();
        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            prop.SetValue(dst, prop.GetValue(src, null), null);
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel there might be a deeper architecture issue here. I'm failing to imagine why would you want to "copy" the values of the properties from one object of a class to another of a different class with the same property names.

If you're trying to "shape" the object maybe just passing an interface will do the work

Anyhow, see if this helps:

```
public static class ObjectMorpher
{
    public class InvalidMorphException : Exception
    {
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class IgnoredOnMorphAttribute : Attribute
    {

    }

    public static TargetType Morph<TargetType>(this object source, TargetType dest, Func<string, string> propertyMatcher = null, bool failOnNoMatch = false)
        where TargetType : class
    {
        if (source == null || dest == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        foreach (var sourceProp in source.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes<IgnoredOnMorphAttribute>().Any() == false))
        {
            var destProp = typeof(TargetType).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == ((propertyMatcher == null) ? sourceProp.Name : propertyMatcher(sourceProp.Name))).FirstOrDefault();
            //check property exists
            if (destProp == null)
            {
                if (failOnNoMatch)
                    throw new InvalidMorphException();
                else
                    continue;
            }
            //check value type is assignable
            if (!destProp.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(sourceProp.GetType()))
            {
                if (failOnNoMatch)
                    throw new InvalidMorphException();
                else
                    continue;
            }
            destProp.SetValue(dest, sourceProp.GetValue(source));
        }
        return dest;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var A = new ClassA();
var B = new ClassB();
B = A.Morph(B);
```

Optionally you can set a property match for the case when properties doesn't have the exact same name.
Also notice the use of the IgnoredOnMorph attribute to mark properties as not morph-able (like calculated properties)

Comment: I found the solution even if it is not optimal, I recovered the objectA data in an arraylist after I modified the objectB data by browsing the arraylist.

Comment: Glad you could solve your own problem! Nonetheless, I'd like you to look forward to solutions that not only work but also might be reusable, easy to maintain and escalate. Exactly what good @Michael and I have tried to provide you with. Happy coding!

Comment: yes, your solution and that of Michael is good. thank you guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You might find automapper of use here (see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started).

You would need to create a line for each object mapping in a startup file to set it up but if the properties are the same this would be as simple as:

```
mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, ClassB>().ReverseMap();
```

And then a single line to resolve the mapping when needed

```
mapper.Map(objectOfClassA, new ClassB());
```